# Python segmentation fault 11 on Mojave

Tags: python, macos, segmentation-fault, wxpython, macos-mojave

MacOS 10.14.5 (Mojave)

Python 3.7.3

wxPython 4.0.6

Keep getting crashes with "Segmentation fault: 11"

For example, I have an app that displays a wx.RearrangeCtrl. It displays and populates OK but Python crashes if I try to check a box or move an item.

I found numerous threads on this topic but they all refer to much older versions, and the solutions they offer are not valid for the current versions.

Any advice would be appreciated.

I wrote a simple app to reproduce the problem. As before, it lints clean, and runs OK initially. The window opens, and the list box gets its three items added. The segmentation fault crash occurs if I try to move an item or check a box. This happens consistently, every time.

```
import wx


class mainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(mainFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        pnl = wx.Panel(self)
        mainsizer = wx.BoxSizer(orient=wx.VERTICAL)

        self.vlist = wx.RearrangeCtrl(pnl)
        self.vlist.Create(pnl, -1, size=(600,400))
        mainsizer.Add(self.vlist, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 10)

        pnl.SetSizerAndFit(mainsizer)

        self.loadList()

    def loadList(self):
        self.vlist.GetList().Append("first line")
        self.vlist.GetList().Append("second line")
        self.vlist.GetList().Append("third line")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frm = mainFrame(None, title='Crash Test', size=wx.Size(800, 600))
    frm.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Can you post some code showing the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code also crashes in macOS 10.14.4 and Win10. The problem seems to be that you must give the list of `items` and `order` during the creation of the [`wx.RearrangeCtrl`](https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.RearrangeCtrl.html?highlight=wx.rearrangectrl#wx.RearrangeCtrl) widget.

The code below is now working fine in both OS.

```
import wx


class mainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(mainFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        pnl = wx.Panel(self)
        mainsizer = wx.BoxSizer(orient=wx.VERTICAL)

        items = ['first line', 'second line', 'third line']
        order = [0, 1, 2]

        self.vlist = wx.RearrangeCtrl(pnl, -1, size=(600, 400), order=order, items=items)

        mainsizer.Add(self.vlist, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 10)

        pnl.SetSizerAndFit(mainsizer)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frm = mainFrame(None, title='Crash Test', size=wx.Size(800, 600))
    frm.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Just in case, the description for showing the items as selected or not is [here](https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.RearrangeList.html#wx-rearrangelist).

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful. I am very frustrated with the wxPython docs - nowhere does it suggest that those are required items. One gets the impression that you can populate the list after creating it.